# Flatten 3d list to 2d in python

Tags: python, list, flatten

So I have a list of lists in python that is something like this:

```
[[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

I want to flatten this list and end up with this:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this in python?

Comment: Could you share a more copy/paste friendly version of the lists?

Comment: please add commas

Comment: ok I changed the list with an easier example.

Comment: You need `list(chain.from_iterable(l))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [numpy.squeeze](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) you can do what you want:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]],
              [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
              [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]],
              [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]])

a.squeeze()

[[0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: @yatu I know, there is already answer for `list`, so I converted list to `np.array`

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]], 
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], 
[[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]], 
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]]    

[i[0] for i in a]
```

output

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```